# How to enable capability with Tuist iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-tools

I use this tool "Tuist" (https://tuist.io) to generate Xcode project. With Tuist we can't edit any settings through Xcode directly. How to enable background mode/notification capability with Tuist

Answer (score 1):

Using tuist means getting rid of the need of maintaining .xcodeproj manually. All relevant settings are defined in the tuist configuration, and by running `tuist generate`, the related .xcodeproj will be generated.

To apply Info.plist changes (the capabilities are defined there), you have to set up a `InfoPlist` dictionary of `[String : InfoPlist.Value]`, and herein, you define whatever you want. For background modes, this is - as an example -  `"UIBackgroundModes": ["fetch", "remote-notification", "remove-notification"]`.
Then, you take that `InfoPlist` definition and provide it to a `Target`of a `Project`, that's it.

The tuist documentation shows the syntax of the available configuration options, as well as some examples. You may want to have a look on medium.com, there are some more articles about working with tuist in practice. (I've written one there about creating a workspace with a main app and various module frameworks.)